# Derivative of an absolute value

Tags: derivatives, absolute-value

I would like to solve the following derivative:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\sum_{k \in U}{\sum_{l \in U}{a_k a_lw_kw_l|y_k-y_l|}}$$

where U is a population and the variable $a$ is equal to "1" if the unit is selected to be part of a sample and "0" otherwise.

Comment: Why don't you consider $\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\sum_{k \in U}{\sum_{l \in U}{a_k a_lw_kw_l(y_k-y_l)^2}}$ which is differentiable ?

Comment: But is it equivalent?

Comment: No, it is not equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of the absolute value is undefined for argument $0$ and is the sign function elsewhere.

Then the derivative on $y_j$:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\sum_{k \in U}{\sum_{l \in U}{a_k a_lw_kw_l|y_k-y_l|}}=\\
\sum_{k \in U}\sum_{l \in U}(a_k a_lw_kw_l\text{ sgn}(y_k-y_l)\delta_{jk}-a_k a_lw_kw_l\text{ sgn}(y_k-y_l)\delta_{jl})=\\
\sum_{l \in U}a_j a_lw_jw_l\text{ sgn}(y_j-y_l)-\sum_{k \in U}a_k a_jw_kw_j\text{ sgn}(y_k-y_j).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I have one question about $\delta$ and its meaning

Comment: This the so-called Kronecker delta.